# Error in Starting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.10, startup, swap

I am running Ubuntu 16.10. It was running fine until I have to increase my disk size.

In increasing the size Swap file was creating problem. So I deleted the swap file. Merged the un-allocated space. and created swap file again using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial.

Now I am trying to start `Ubuntu` and here is what I am getting. It looks like deleting the swap space created the problem. How to solve it ? I have my thesis data in it

`Startx` is also not working

[image]
[image]

Out put of Commands as asked in comments.

[image]

Comment: You followed a guide for Ubuntu 14.04 server (so no GUI) on Ubuntu 16.10 (also server?), it's more than usual to have problems! Try to stick with guides for the same version that you are using!  Did you try to investigate the problem as suggested in the first screenshot? What are the systemd logs that you get from that command?

Comment: I'll have to ask you for a lot of information. Please make sure to give me all of the answers. Edit the output into your question. In `terminal`... `sudo blkid`, `cat /etc/fstab`, `ls -al /swapfile`, `lsblk`, and a screenshot of `gparted`. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` and let me know when you have this info.

Comment: @dadexix86 I have made swap file before from that same tutorial. and I am not much aware to ubuntu so its totally Alien to me what it is trying to say.  I dont know where to find those logs.

Comment: @heynnema I have added screenshot take a look please.

Comment: I'll bet that you forgot the `sudo mkswap /swapfile` step. Report back.

Comment: Where's your mount for / in /etc/fstab?

Comment: wait a bit I update it

Comment: I dont know what are you asking. by saying 
"Where's your mount for / in /etc/fstab? " I have added all information as you required. kindly explain it.

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to put together an answer for you...

Answer (score 2):

You have 2-3 different problems.

**Problem #1:**

First, after looking at your `cat /etc/fstab`, I notice that there's no mount for `/`. See where it says `# / was mounted on /dev/sda1 during installation`? The very next line should look **something** like this:

```
UUID=255a75c0-4c63-4630-945f-e42afa1a8b15   /   ext4  errors=remount-ro     0       1
```

To edit in the proper UUID number, first do this:

```
sudo blkid
```

and copy the UUID for `/dev/sda1` to the clipboard, and **replace** the UUID in my example from above with a paste from the clipboard. Add that line to your `/etc/fstab`.

**Note:** if it tells you that you can't edit/save `/etc/fstab` because it's on a read-only file system, do the following command, then edit `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

**Problem #2:**

When you created the `/swapfile`, you followed instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04, but you probably forgot to do the following step:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

**Problem #3:**

If this is a UEFI computer, I don't see a partition for `/boot/efi`. Normally I'd expect `/etc/fstab` to contain lines **similar** to these:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=3084-EB11    /boot/efi      vfat       defaults              0       1
```

Was this there before, or did you accidentally delete the partition and the above lines in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: What if I tell you i removed those lines by mistake.

Comment: Did you also delete more than just the swap partition? You should be able to fix problem #1 and #2 with my answer, and maybe your machine will boot properly.

Comment: Problem #1 is the only really critical one. Having a swap file is helpful, but not absolutely necessary. Mounting the ESP at `/boot/efi` is necessary to install updates to GRUB and a few other tools, but is otherwise unnecessary. Chances are the main symptom (a read-only mount of the root filesystem) is caused by problem #1. Note that, if the read-only status of `/` persists to login, you'll need to manually remount it read-write or use an emergency disk to make the change to `/etc/fstab` specified in this answer.

Comment: @RodSmith I think problem #1 came after problem #2, and was created by the user editing fstab. The swap problem happened first, as you can see by the first image... and the user deleting partition(s), etc. I added the remount to my answer, thanks.

Comment: Sure, #1 may have followed #2; but right now, #1 is the issue that's causing actual problems in using the system, if I understand correctly. I'm simply advising focusing on #1 to get the system working in a moderately acceptable way. Once that issue is resolved, the others will become easier to solve, and can be tackled as time permits.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the cat /etc/fstab error that happens when manually create the swap.

Try at terminal:

blkid

Then copy the Id of the swap partition, and paste it replacing the old one at:

sudo nano /etc/fstab

If the swap is not created yet then just comment the entire line of the old swap (# at the beginning of the line).

Comment: swap is not created yet. i have added one more screenshot

Comment: This answer is incomplete, and incorrect. Please update/correct it.